# Index creation in extremely slow in Mysql Aurora 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, index-tuning, aws-aurora

I have a table in mysql Aurora 5.7 version .

The db instance has very good configuration 488 GB ram (db.r4.16xlarge).

Data base is static data base no application is running on this .

I have 1.5 Billions record approx 2TB size in the table .

The table does not have any index except primary key .

Table has 35 Columns .

This table does not have any partition

Now i need to create Index on nine other columns and here i hit hard .
It takes 5 Hours to create one index and when i run command to create all 9 index at same time it took almost 10 hours and then i cancelled .

Is there any way i can make this index creation faster ?
Is creating 10 partition will help creating Index faster ?

Why i need to create Index on 1.5 Billions records is because i have migrated my table from Orcale Source to Mysql using AWS DMS service .

Before migration i need to drop index at target and then have to migrate so that migration will be faster  and it is actually very fast .

Without Index migration took 10 hours where as with Index it is taking 25 Hours and some time it fails as well .

Comment: How many drives are supporting the 2TB table?

Comment: @MichaelKutz sorry i did not get how many drivers ?

Comment: How many physical drives are in your system? What is the RAID configuration? What is the sustainable throughput of your disk subsystem? How fast can you copy 2TB of data? Does your expected `CREATE INDEX` time coincide with what your system can handle? Did you run benchmarks on the I/O subsystem before hand? If so, what are the results?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for reducing index creation time required.

Comment: Is that 9 single-column indexes?  That is rarely optimal.  Let's see the queries that need them; there may be some 'composite' indexes that will help even more.

Comment: @WilsonHauck and MichaelKutz the OP said this is Amazon Aurora. It's a managed database, users have no access to the host. Storage is distributed and virtualized, so there is no access to know the drivers, the RAID, the `iostat` metrics, or anything else.

Comment: @BillKarwin  Is this URL of no value for an Amazon Aurora client?  --- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-poc.html#Aurora.Poc.Practice

Comment: @WilsonHauck Correct, that is of no use to view or monitor the details of the physical infrastructure. Aurora storage is virtualized and distributed over three availability zones. Obviously at some level there are physical devices, but that's layers below what you can view, and you cannot ssh to the hosts anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of rows., every row has to be inserted into the index, that takes time, live with it.

You can try to use only one index for all columns

```
CREATE INDEX name 
ON yourtable(column1,column2,column3,column4...colmn9);
```

That takes also long, but should be faster

Comment: Does partitioning will help ?

Comment: @AtharvThakur   No, partitions it will only complicate your life.

Comment: `INDEX(a,b)` versus `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` -- _These are not equivalent._  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1

Comment: With 2 or more columns, the overwhelming majority of SO  prefer combined index when they are used together

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning rarely helps with performance.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Adding an index to a partitioned table probably takes longer than to the equivalent non-partitioned table -- it will block access throughout the action.

There have been several important changes to Oracle's MySQL; Aurora may not have picked them up yet.  (I don't know how close Aurora 5.7 is to MySQL 5.7.)  You tagged the question `[mysql-5.6]`; which is it?

Let's see the actual indexes you what to add; there may be some tricks and/or cautions to discuss.

In general, it is *not* useful to index "flags" or other low-cardinality columns.  That is, if they are alone in the index.

Prefixing is rarely useful.  Example: `INDEX(foo(10))`

Percona Toolkit *may* have something to help.

Let's see the queries that need them; there may be some 'composite' indexes that will help even more.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.